# Tag manager en body

Tags: php, html

Hola buenas estoy intentado poner el codigo del body de tagmanager y no me deja ponerlo me
da error de todas maneras

```html
<body
 <?php body_class(); ?> data-be-site-layout='<?php echo $be_themes_data['layout']; ?>' data-be-page-template = '<?php echo basename(get_page_template(),".php"); ?>' >  
    <?php
    do_action( 'after_body' );
        if( $be_themes_data['opt-header-type'] !== 'builder' ){
            $widget_style = (isset($be_themes_data['seach_widget_style']) && !empty($be_themes_data['seach_widget_style'])) ? $be_themes_data['seach_widget_style'] : 'style1-header-search-widget';
            if($widget_style == 'style2-header-search-widget') {
                be_themes_get_header_search_form_widget( false, true);
            }
            if ( ('left' == $be_themes_data['opt-header-type'] ) && isset($be_themes_data['left-header-style']) ){
                $opt_header_type = 'left';
            } else if( ('top' == $be_themes_data['opt-header-type'] ) && isset($be_themes_data['opt-header-type']) ){
                $opt_header_type = 'top';
            }
            // based on the choice of header style call its header-default.php
            get_template_part('headers/'.$opt_header_type.'/header', 'default');
        }else{
            do_action( 'tatsu_print_header' );
            get_template_part( 'headers/top', 'section' );
        }
        do_action( 'tatsu_head' );
```

y este el de tag manager  que va  body que es lo que no consigo poner en mi tema de wordpress

```html
<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-TQKVLQR"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
```

Comment: y el error cual es???

Comment: Te recomiendo que pases a la lecturas de los siguientes artículos: 
[ask] y 
[mre] y 
[help/on-topic] y 
[help/dont-ask]

Answer (score 0):

aquí hay una guía para hacerlo, me parece que estás usando Wordpress. Con un plugin puedes agregarlo al header:
https://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-install-and-setup-google-tag-manager-in-wordpress/

Sin embargo, si quieres hacerlo manual cómo has intentado, ve al administrador de archivos, busca `/wp-content/themes/tutema`

En mi caso es Newspaper, así que sería `/wp-content/themes/Newspaper/header.php`

Ya ahí, solo pega el código TAL CUAL de TagManager despues de `<body>`.

En caso de que no sea wordpress:

```
<body>
<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-TQKVLQR"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->

 <?php body_class(); ?> data-be-site-layout='<?php echo $be_themes_data['layout']; ?>' data-be-page-template = '<?php echo basename(get_page_template(),".php"); ?>' >  
    <?php
    do_action( 'after_body' );
        if( $be_themes_data['opt-header-type'] !== 'builder' ){
            $widget_style = (isset($be_themes_data['seach_widget_style']) && !empty($be_themes_data['seach_widget_style'])) ? $be_themes_data['seach_widget_style'] : 'style1-header-search-widget';
            if($widget_style == 'style2-header-search-widget') {
                be_themes_get_header_search_form_widget( false, true);
            }
            if ( ('left' == $be_themes_data['opt-header-type'] ) && isset($be_themes_data['left-header-style']) ){
                $opt_header_type = 'left';
            } else if( ('top' == $be_themes_data['opt-header-type'] ) && isset($be_themes_data['opt-header-type']) ){
                $opt_header_type = 'top';
            }
            // based on the choice of header style call its header-default.php
            get_template_part('headers/'.$opt_header_type.'/header', 'default');
        }else{
            do_action( 'tatsu_print_header' );
            get_template_part( 'headers/top', 'section' );
        }
        do_action( 'tatsu_head' );
```

Pero porfavor revisa que sea después del body.